# How to solve mechanics problem when acceleration depends on position.

Tags: integration, classical-mechanics

I'm curious about how problems such as the following are typically solved analytically, or in computer simulations such as games engines for 2D physics. It seems a bit harder than the typical constant acceleration scenario.

Suppose a particle with mass m is free to move inside a smooth 2D basin given by the curve $y=x^2$. Given some initial conditions, such as position $(x_0, x_0^2)$, the problem is to determine the position of the particle at time $t$.

The particle is always subject to a gravitational force $(0, -mg)$. The other force acting on it is the reaction from the basin, which has magnitude $mg$, and direction given by the unit normal to the basin at the current position, $\hat{\mathbf{n}}(x)$.

Solving for position at time $t$ requires integrating the velocity, and thus the acceleration, up until time $t$. But the acceleration at time $t$ depends on the current position to obtain the normal vector. So it is not clear to me (or I have forgotten) how this can be solved analytically.

As well as the question of how this would be solved analytically, I'm also interested in how this may typically be implemented in simulation software. It seems like if you went for a finite element method, however small your time step, you would be moving out of contact with the basin if you took steps along the tangent vector.

Comment: I would think that in any simulation like this you would want cater for the possibility of humps in the basin (FORTUNA or PINBALL!!!!), when the particle WILL lose the contact with the rail. That happens only when the speed vector exits the rail. After all the basin will act on the particle only, when the particle attempts to enter the basin. Mind you, I don't think that the reaction force has magnitude $mg$. The reaction force is just large enough to prevent the particle from entering. The difference of the two forces will accelerate the particle in the direction of the tangent.

Comment: (cont'd) That is, while the particle and the basin remain in contact.

Comment: What is "typical" depends on the nature of the application.  If the simulation is for purposes of a game, then accuracy may not be very important.  If simulation is for a more serious purpose, such as an n-body gravitational scenario, then you may want accuracy if only to observe possible chaotic behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe that:
$$V=mgy=mgx^2$$ and the kinetic energy can be written as:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)$$
Bacause you know: $y=x^2$, you get: $\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{dx}\dot{x}=2x\dot{x}$
So you can write the Eulero Lagrange equations putting $L=T-V$ (Lagrangian):
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$$
Writing this equation you get a nonlinear differential equation and if you are luky you can obtain an analytical expression for $x(t)$ and so for $y(t)$

Comment: This is great, thanks. I looked up the [Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian) on Wikipedia and that gave me lots of helpful info. I end up with a second-order ODE which looks like:
$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 4 x^2 \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 4 x {\frac{dx}{dt}}^2 + 2gx = 0.$ Next I need to try and remember how this can be solved ... with Sturm-Liouville theory IIRC...